# Split column which has different records into rows in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have one table, which has combination of single values and comma separated values in multiple columns as per below table:

| No | Records | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A,B | F,G | D,E,F | Noval | Noval | Z,U |
| 2 | Z | X | Noval | P,Q,R | S,T | Noval |

The required output must be like below,

| No | Records | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | F | D | Noval | Noval | Z |
| 1 | B | G | E | Noval | Noval | U |
| 1 | null | null | F | null | null | null |
| 2 | Z | X | Noval | P | S | Noval |
| 2 | Z | X | Noval | Q | T | Noval |
| 2 | Z | X | Noval | R | null | Noval |

How to obatin this result with `unnest` and `split` in BigQuery?

Comment: Please help me understand this concept

Comment: what is the datatype for `records` is it repeatable (list) or just string.

Comment: String is the datatype

Comment: You want to unnest all entries. But for "Noval" this shall be written to all unnested outputs (example value2 for No=2).  But in your example  for No=1, Records=null, value3 and value4 shall be null. Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

First each column needs to be split be comma. Then the unnest comes into play. If unnest is done for each column all combination are created. By using the offset, elimination of unwanted combination is possible.

```
WITH
  tbl AS (
  SELECT
    SPLIT('A,B') AS Records,
    SPLIT('F,G') AS value1)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl,
  UNNEST(Records) AS Records_name WITH OFFSET Records_id,
  UNNEST(value1) AS value1_name WITH OFFSET value1_id
WHERE Records_id=value1_id
```

However, this will fail, if different lengths of array are present. Therefore, we generate an array `tmp` for the numbers 0 to 10.000. For each number we take the entry of the array. If the number is greater than the array size, we take the last entry.

```
IF(tmp>=ARRAY_LENGTH(value1),value1[SAFE_OFFSET(ARRAY_LENGTH(value1)-1)], value1[SAFE_OFFSET(tmp)]) as value1,
```

This can be written better as

```
value1[SAFE_OFFSET(LEAST(ARRAY_LENGTH(value1)-1,tmp))] AS value1,
```

The `WHERE` condition removes unneeded entries where `tmp` is larger than the greatest array size.

```sql
WITH
  tbl AS (
  SELECT
    1 AS row_num,
    'A,B' AS Records,
    'F,G' AS value1,
    'D,E' AS value2,
    'Noval' AS value3,
    'Noval' AS value4,
    'Z,U' AS value5
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    2,
    'Z',
    'X',
    'Noval',
    'P,Q',
    'S,T',
    'Noval' ),
  tbl1 AS (
  SELECT
    row_num,
    SPLIT(Records) AS Records,
    SPLIT(value1) AS value1,
    SPLIT(value2) AS value2,
    SPLIT(value3) AS value3,
    SPLIT(value4) AS value4,
    SPLIT(value5) AS value5,
  FROM
    tbl ),
  tbl2 AS (
  SELECT
    row_num,
    tmp,
    Records[SAFE_OFFSET(LEAST(ARRAY_LENGTH(Records)-1,tmp))] AS value1,
    value1[SAFE_OFFSET(LEAST(ARRAY_LENGTH(value1)-1,tmp))] AS value1,
    value2[SAFE_OFFSET(LEAST(ARRAY_LENGTH(value2)-1,tmp))] AS value2,
    value3[SAFE_OFFSET(LEAST(ARRAY_LENGTH(value3)-1,tmp))] AS value3,
    value4[SAFE_OFFSET(LEAST(ARRAY_LENGTH(value4)-1,tmp))] AS value4,
    value5[SAFE_OFFSET(LEAST(ARRAY_LENGTH(value5)-1,tmp))] AS value5,
  FROM
    tbl1,
    UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,10000)) AS tmp
  WHERE
    tmp<GREATEST(ARRAY_LENGTH(value1),ARRAY_LENGTH(value2),ARRAY_LENGTH(value3),ARRAY_LENGTH(value4),ARRAY_LENGTH(value5)) )
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl2
```